# Checking the proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

[image]

That is the problem I'm working on.
I want to check if there are any errors in my logic.

I will prove first: $\phi^{-1}(H)$ is a subgroup of $G$,   second: $K \subset \phi^{-1}(H)$

First part proof:

(1) Check closure.

Take $a, b \in \phi^{-1}(H)$. Then $\phi(a), \phi(b) \in H $

This means that $\phi(ab) \in H$ because $\phi(ab) = \phi(a)\phi(b) \in H$

Then $ab \in \phi^{-1}(H),$ so it's closed.

(2) check inverse

Take $a \in \phi^{-1}(H)$.  Then $\phi(a) \in H$.

Since $H$ is a subgroup, $\phi(a)^{-1} = \phi(a^{-1}) \in H.$

Then $a^{-1} \in \phi^{-1}(H).$

(3) check identity

Since $H$ is a subgroup, $e \in \phi^{-1}(H).$ So $\phi(e) \in H,$ and $e \in \phi^{-1}(H)$

Second part proof:

Take $x \in K$. Then $\phi(x) = e'$, where $e'$ is the identity of $G'$.

Since $H$ is a subgroup of $G'$, $\phi(x) \in H$. Then $x \in \phi^{-1}(H)$. So $K \subset \phi^{-1}(H)$

Comment: proof is alright

Comment: whew Thank you for reviewing!

Comment: For (3), you should have written $\phi(e)=e'\in H\implies e\in\phi^{-1}(H)$.

Comment: @Berci thanks for the correction!

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.